# Cypress (javascript) 'else' block executes even when the first 'if' statement condition is true

Tags: javascript, if-statement, user-interface, cypress

New to Cypress and JavaScript, Please help

I was automating the test case to check the enabled/disabled state of the button on the condition of a few elements to have 'src' html attribute with a value '/Client/images/iconNo.png' (button will be disabled) and /Client/images/iconYes.png (button will be enabled).

I used if statement to check the above condition by wrapping the objects to get the value and using '.then()' method, below is the javascript code

```
cy.get('.eligibilitySuccessfulGrant > :nth-child(1) > .cursor')
  .then(($checkListIcon) =>{

    if(cy.wrap($checkListIcon).should('have.attr', 'src', '/Client/images/iconNo.png')){

        verifyQIAPTab.clickRequestOrientation().should('be.disabled')
    }
    else (cy.wrap($checkListIcon).should('have.attr', 'src', '/Client/images/iconYes.png'))
    {
         verifyQIAPTab.clickRequestOrientation().should('be.enabled').click()
}
})
```

**Problem**: if the first 'if' statement is true then it should pass the test case but the cypress is throwing an error that the else condition is not satisfied.

this is the cypress error:
[image: below is the cypress error:]

where the cypress is checking that `.should('be.enabled').click()` condition.
How can I resolve this?

OR

Is there any other way in cypress to check my above test case?

Please help and suggest
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

Cypress commands are Asynchronous. That means you're better off using two separate if conditions. Moreover, you are wrapping the same element thrice. Using javascript assertions in combination with cypress commands would be a lot better.

This [hasAttribute](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-hasattribute/) method for example can help you remove the assertion from the if condition.

Please share inner HTML for the buttons so I can help you further.

Comment: Moreover, don't chain the should assertion with click(), you're better off writing two separate statements.

Comment: Thanks for help, I will try this approach

Comment: I have added the inner HTML code

Comment: What is verifyQIAPTab? Please explain. I need to understand what you're chaining. You're chaining two things with the should assertion without wrapping it. Should is a mocha assertion used by Cypress.  I suggest looking up the [expect]( https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/) assertion as well.

Comment: verifyQIAPTab? was a nothing but cy.get('elementid'), it was a Page Object Model. Now the issue resolved with help of return in else block

Answer (score 1):

Cannot use a Cypress command to perform an `if()`, commands always return an object not true/false.

Use jQuery in place of command

```
if ($checkListIcon.attr('src') === '/Client/images/iconNo.png')
```

Comment: Hi @Mihi thanks for the help, I used the JQuery, but the output is having the same behavior as I mentioned above. here is the code `cy.get('.eligibilitySuccessfulGrant > :nth-child(1) > .cursor')
      .then(($checkListIcon) =>{

        if($checkListIcon.attr('src') ===  '/Client/images/iconNo.png'){

            verifyQIAPTab.clickRequestOrientation().should('be.disabled')}
        else ($checkListIcon.attr('src') ===  '/Client/images/iconYes.png')
        {
             verifyQIAPTab.clickRequestOrientation().should('be.enabled').click()}
    })`

Comment: It could be wrong selector -  this one `'.eligibilitySuccessfulGrant > :nth-child(1) > .cursor'`. Check with `console.log($checkListIcon.attr('src'))`